# Time complexity of constant array slicing in a loop

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, time-complexity, slice

What would be the complexity of the code below?

In my view, it would be **`O(N).`**

Even though we have array slicing inside the for loop that takes `O(K)` in [python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), it would always run for constant time i.e. equals to `pairLength`. So for instance, if the length of string i.e. `st` is 6 and `pairLength` is 3 the total it would run is `6*3=12`times. Similarly, if we have `st` of size 12, it would run 36 times. Here is the confusion, we could also say it as `O(N*M)` but M is always constant (once set i.e. pairLength) so we can consider it as `O(N)`. Is it correct?

**edit:** Let's assume `pairLength` is constant and it is 3 all the time. Would the complexity be O(N) then?

```
def writeAllCombinations(st, pairLength):
    for i in range((len(st)-pairLength)+1):
        print(st[i:i+pairLength]) # could also be done using inner loops and concat

# calling function
writeAllCombinations("HelloWorld", 3)
```

Comment: What is N in your example?

Comment: `pairLength` is a parameter, not a constant.

Comment: length of the string (st) or the loop that would roughly run len(st) times.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica: Let's assume pairLength was not a param and it was 3 all the time. Would the complexity be O(N) then?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming pairLength is a constant, len(st) being N.
Obviously, the for loop runs `N - pairLength + 1` times = O(N) time.

In each step of the for loop,
assuming `st` is a list, then `st[i:i+pairLength]` takes O(1) time. `print` can also be assumed O(1) time in this case.

Therefore, we could conclude that, the function takes O(N) time.

Comment: I have confusion here `st[i:i+pairLength]`. Slicing is actually O(K or pairLength) in python. But if `pairLength` is always the same value then slicing would be considered as constant time i.e. O(1) ?